# joomla extension installation errors

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, joomla

I always recieve  this message:

> 'Error:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 SQL=INSERT INTO
>   #__crowdf_currencies (id, title, code, symbol, position) VALUES ()'

whenever I wanted  to  import the currencies  database  with  currencies import manager. In joomla crowdfunding platform

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem.

I dropped the table from the database, then re-installed component, which adds the table back. Next I ran clean database function, which re-saves each item and inturn repopulates the table. Now everything is working correctly.

Comment: Thank,you  mean i  should i should go to  my  phpadmin and remove  the  currencies table and  then  re-import  the  currencies  database  through the crowdfunding platform

Comment: Thanks Pawel,And how  and where should  I  run the  database  function. Should I  create  a  new  file  for  that.